# How to use groupBy to summarize data

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem about summarize data (its like pivot table in excel)

I have an employee table with Model `Employee`

Here the code to find data in a specific range

```
$Latelist = Employee::whereBetween('date', [$searchFrom, $searchUntil])
    ->where('clockin', '!=', '')
    ->where('late', '!=', '')
    ->get();
```

My question is how to summarize data like a pivot table in excel?

Eliminate multiple names to have a name **once** and the `totalLate`.

Output data should be

```
name    | totalLate
-------------------------
name1   | 3
name2   | 2
name3   | 5
```

Thank you

Comment: How does your pivot table is structorued? where is saved how much late user has?

Comment: Note that unless employees work exactly one shift, you wouldn't normally store clock-in details in a table called 'employee'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` and `SUM` for the same

```
$Latelist      = Employee::whereBetween('date', [$searchfrom,$searchuntil])
        ->where('clockin', '!=' , "")
        ->where('late', '!=' , "")
        ->selectRaw("SUM(late) as totalLate") // add this
        ->groupBy("name") // add this

            ->get();
```